# What is the meaning of this Java code?

Tags: java, syntax, label, case

It happened to me recently to write a piece of code similar to this one:

```
switch (x) {
    case a: case b: case c:
    // do something
    break;
    case d: case e: case f:
    // do something
    break;
}
```

Then, I got wrong and wrote a similar code with a syntax error: I forgot to write the case keyword:

```
switch (x) {
    case a: b: c:
    // do something
    break;
    case d: e: f:
    // do something
    break;
}
```

This syntax is actually *valid* in some other languages and the switch passes through all the values.

Actually here is valid too, as I did not get any syntax error: but a wrong behaviour by the program that was executing the switch smoothly, only missing the values without the case keyword.

Why? What does the b; c:, e: and f: mean in the second snip?

Are they maybe **labels**? And then, how could they possibly be on the same line? What am I missing that I don't understand behind this weird non-error?

Edit: they appear to be indeed **labels**. It's unusual and as @Bathsheba explained, the problem is that labels are generally at the begin of a line. Weird how Java allows such a confusing (in my mind) syntax, without even showing a warning. **This can create really a lot of confusion and weird errors in long programs.**

Thank you.

Comment: Can I know why I got -2 in 10 seconds? What's wrong in this question? I'm trying to understand something more deep about Java syntax.

Comment: I like this question. It's well put, with good code snippets.

Comment: Because if you had Googled "How does a switch statement work" you would have gotten the answer. Basically the question you asked if, why isn't the code with broken syntax working. Answer : Because it has broken syntax.

Comment: Nope, I asked why the code *works* with wrong syntax.

Comment: @DejaVuSansMono: not true: this code is syntactically correct.

Comment: @Bathsheba Then it's breaking to label. I would like this question if it were clearer. Maybe a quick edit would make this more palatable.

Comment: No it's not breaking to a label. But the labels are there all the same.

Comment: @Bathsheba Curious. Fine, question get's an upvote for unexpected intrigue.

Comment: I tried to make it clearer :D and yes... it was a curiosity, nothing more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the second case, `b:`, `c:`, `e:`, and `f:` are *labels*. You are allowed to `break` to a label in Java, and the language allows you to insert a label in all sorts of places, including the places where you have.

It's just unusual to see labels not starting at the beginning of a line, that's all.

Comment: So labels are *stackable* on the same line and within a same block, appearantly

Comment: I'm afraid so ;-(

Comment: Well, Java since its birth wants to help developers obliging them to use clear syntax and patterns, and avoid usual errors, it's very strange to find that such an abnormal syntax twist, it remembers me more c than Java :) Thank you